# Plotting Bar graph with logarithmic x axis

Tags: matlab, graph, statistics, bar-chart, logarithm

I have a matrix with 2 columns that I would like to display in a bar graph. The **y axis** should be in **intervals of 5** and the **x axis** in a **logarithmic scale of base 10**.

As an example I have a matrix [45660 0 ; 3213 5 ; 45631 10 ; 45631 15 ; 300 20]

I found a way to display these points with a logarithmic scale on the x axis, but I would like it to be a bar graph to make it easier to see which 'y' value the points are corresponding to. The width of each bar can be from the x axis value of one point to the x axis value of the next.

```
PeakCount1=[Load_range Load_count]; 

semilogx(PeakCount1(:,2),PeakCount1(:,1),'.','MarkerSize',15);
xlabel('Number of Peaks')
ylabel('Load Range (kN)')
title('Number of Peaks Occurring Within Maximum Ice Load Range');
saveas(gcf,'PeakCount_Loadlevels','bmp')
```

Comment: Could you show the code you used to get a log scale on the x axis? That may make it easier to help.

Comment: use a different value for `XData` and `XTick` one in log scale and one in linear scale.

Comment: the x axis values are the number of cycles occurring at that y value and the number of peaks occurring in a group is completely random. But here is the code of how I plotted the graph with a log scale on x axis

Comment: What is XData and XTick?

Answer (score 3):

What about using

```
stem(PeakCount1(:,2),PeakCount1(:,1),'LineWidth',10.0);
set(gca,'XScale','log');
```

Instead using `stem` you can use any plot function you like, just insert the second line to make the `x` axis log.

Comment: thanks that works quite well! The only thing is that the bars are extremely thin. Is there a way to set their width?

Comment: You can add `'LineWidth',number` to stem, see edit of the answer.

Comment: oh yes that makes it easier, but using the bar function I cannot get all of the results into bars. Im guessing this because they are closely packed. But I will keep trying different plot functions